# ng-model is undefined in controller when i pass as function parameters via ng-click

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to design a view that simply takes firstName and lastName via ng-model then passes it to a CreateAccount function in the controller via ng-click. I can't seem to get it working correctly and in console, value for firstName and lastName is shown as undefined even after filling all details.

HTML

```
<ion-view title="USER">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <p ng-click="CreateAccount(FirstName,LastName)">
           SAVE
        </p>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
<ion-content>    
    <md-input-container md-no-float="">
        <div>
            <input class="user-name" 
                   placeholder="First Name"
                   ng-model="FirstName">
        </div>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container md-no-float="">
        <div>
            <input class="user-name" 
                   placeholder="Last Name"
                   ng-model="LastName">
        </div>
    </md-input-container>
</ion-content>  
</ion-view>
```

Controller

```
$scope.CreateAccount = function(FirstName,LastName){
    console.log(FirstName);
    console.log(LastName);
}
```

Comment: Assuming It is in scope,you don't need to pass it as parameter. Try using `console.log($scope.FirstName)` and `console.log($scope.LastName)`

Answer (score 0):

You should have the variables defiend , if you have the $scope variable  no need to pass inside the function

```
  $scope.person = {
       firstName: "Nikhil",
       lastName: "Hegde"
     };
     $scope.save =function() {
       console.log($scope.person.firstName);
        console.log($scope.person.lastName);
     };
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/m4ZEAwTKrE4XfvkaAqKU?p=info)